# SSIS tasks are getting fail with Communication link failure error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, business-intelligence

In a SSIS package I have an OLED Source, a look up transformation and an OLE DB destination task. I'm running my package on VS 2019 but the tasks(OLED Source, OLE DB destination) are getting fail after 10 to 15 minutes with below error:

```
[OLE DB Destination [27]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Communication link failure".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired.
".
[OLE DB Destination [27]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (27) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (40). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[OLE DB Source [66]] Error: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on OLE DB Source returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

I tried to fix this issue by setting `validateExternalMetadata` as `false` for the tasks but no luck.
I also checked others answers on stack overflow for almost the similar issues/ques. but that also didn't help.
`Note:` SSIS connection manager is using `SQL server authentication` and DB is `Azure SQL`

appreciate your help if any.

Comment: Does it load any data during the 10-15 minutes before it fails?

Comment: @Cedersved, yes It loads around 2000 matched records to destination before failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience this error can have various reasons. For example this can be caused by the server being overloaded, or due to bad network. One thing you could try is to change the caching mode of your lookup component. I'm assuming it's running in "Full cache" mode, meaning that all the data in the lookups query will be read into memory of the SSIS server before doing the lookup. Changing this to "No cache" for example will result in the lookup query being run for every row that's fed into the component. "Partial cache" will cache, but only as each distinct value is encountered in the data flow. These other methods will put less load on memory of the SSIS server but more load on the lookup source database. If it works one option might be to increase RAM of the SSIS server.

Comment: It was running in default Look up mode "full cache" but changed to "partial cache" then also was failing, when changed to "no cache" mode it ran successfully. Thank you @Cedersved

Comment: how to change the Cache mode? steps please...

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using a deprecated "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"

Starting from 2018, it is better to use **Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server**

It is optimized for Azure, and has lots of new functionality.

- [Released: Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlnativeclient/released-microsoft-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server)
- [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you @Yitzhak Khabinsky for answering.

Comment: @Hussain, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.